# Why does reindexing fail when trying to solve this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite sum in question is $\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ (I'm writing my sums in general Sigma-notation) which I broke down into $\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n + 1)$. Writing out the partial sum and seeing the pattern, you can prove that it obviously diverges. However, when solving telescopic series, I like to reindex because it's easier, but when I reindex, I get that it converges as shown below.

$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n + 1)$$
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{1\leq n - 1\leq\infty} ln((n - 1) + 1 )$$
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{1 + 1\leq n\leq\infty + 1} ln(n)$$
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{2\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n)$$
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \left(\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - ln(1)\right)$$
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) - \sum_{1\leq n\leq\infty} ln(n) + 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow converges$$

I've looked over this over and over and feel as if I'm doing something dumb or missing something. Someone explained to me that in the partial sum $S_n = ln(1) + (ln(2) - ln(2)) + (ln(3) - ln(3))... - ln(n+1)$ that because there will always be that last term which doesn't have a pair, that it will approach negative infinity and therefore diverge, but I don't get this because of the fact that there are an infinite amount of terms means that the last $ln(n + 1)$ term will always have a pair to cancel it out which is the next $ln(n)$ term in the series. I see how the limit of the partial sum diverges, but by my reasoning, it has to converge at infinity.
So there are two questions here, why does reindexing fail in this scenario and what is wrong about my thought process with the partial sum?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the reindexing what fails. The problem is that you split a convergent series as a difference of two divergent series.

In general, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n + b_n) \ne \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n  + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n $. If you consult this theorems in a textbook you'll find that you need the hypothesis of both series of the RHS to be convergent.

Comment: The original series is divergent too!

Answer (score 1):

Infinite series are odd beasts and if you rearrange terms you can get different convergence properties. Redo your algebra but replacing infinity with a large number $N$. You'll get, as the final result,

$$
\sum_{1\leq n \leq N} \ln(n) - \sum_{2 \leq n \leq N+1} \ln(n) = \ln(1) - \ln(N+1)
$$

This $-\ln(N+1)$ term that appears in every partial sum is swept under the rug by your telescoping manipulations that allow cancellation of terms all the way up to $N \to \infty$. Qualitatively, its as though you've staggered the two series and ignored the place where one "overhangs" the other at infinity.